# Netsuite Custom Lists (Sub lists?) - Adding and Retrieving data

Tags: php, api, soap, netsuite

We have a NetSuite Electronic Payments bundle installed, which adds a new tab (Bank Payments Details) for Customers, Vendors, etc records. The tab contains lists with basic bank account data (account name, account number, sort code).

Now my question is how do I add and retrieve information from that tab/list? I figured out how to do this with Address tab, as there are dedicated classes for the addresses in the phptoolkit (2014_1). However there's nothing like that for the this new tab. Makes sense, since it's a custom tab.

Ideally all I currently want to do is to add a new vendor with some basic info, address and bank details and be able to update the info later on. I can do all of this aside from the bank details bit.

Can anyone push me into the right direction? The documentation is rather sparse, so it's not a big help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to view the list of record types added by the Electronic Payments bundle, either in the bundle details, or the list of custom records. Additionally, you can inspect the  page source using chrome (or any other modern browser).